# How to make stripes on a cylinder

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to make a Saturn V rocket in blender 2.8 but I have some difficulty with making stripes on a cylinder.

[image: Saturn V]

I'm trying to make the black and white stripes of some stages but I don't know how to do it. I tried with UV Map but my cylinder has too many edges so it's hard to modify the UV map. I also tried with wave texture, mapping and color ramp nodes but I can't adjust the position of the stripes and if I change the scale it just adds more stripes.

[image: The result of wave texture]

Does someone have an idea of what I could do ?

Comment: UV Cylinder Projection, use that with the wave texture. Just a hint, I can make an answer from that later if no one does

Comment: I'd like to see that answer @HenrikD!  I could probably muddle through it myself but I'd appreciate seeing a nicely written up explanation of how and why, and it'll probably be more generally useful for later than my per-face solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's certainly possible to do this procedurally (as the comment from HenrikD is suggesting) I think I'd probably do this via material assignment.

It looks like you already have sufficient numbers of faces on the cylinder to pick the appropriate width, so I'd put an all black material on some faces and an all white material on others.  The white material is simply the default I get when I press the New material button, and the Black material is that default but with the colour changed to a very dark grey.

[image: Buttons to press to add materials and assign to faces]

First add the two material slots (button marked 1) and then with the slot you want (probably Black, assuming the object starts out White by default), select some faces in Edit mode and press Assign (button marked 2).  The Assign button will only show up when actually in Edit mode though.

Here's what this looks like in edit mode (lookdev):

[image: edit mode screenshot]

And here's the result in object mode (lookdev) with overlays off: [image]

This way you can specify exactly which faces you'd like black and which faces you'd like white.  This works very well for cylinders as they tend to have faces exactly where you want to separate the materials, though you may need to plan ahead to have a number of faces divisible by the number of stripes you want.  A procedural solution would not have this issue and would be better in some other ways, but requires more setup and tweaking.

If I needed this to be a single material UV mapped texture, I'd then probably bake it out to a diffuse texture map.  I think explaining the process for doing so is a bit long for this answer but you can check out the blender manual on the subject or find one of many video tutorials on that subject, but I'll link one or attempt to expand the answer if requested.

Comment: I don't see any assign button in 2.8 Edit: It was just on the right side in the proprieties window

Comment: Is their a way to select example 1/8 faces?

Comment: Assign only shows up in Edit mode.  In the dropdown Select menu in edit mode when editing faces, try Checker Deselect.  You'll probably have to play with it a bit but using it and then maybe select less should get you 1/8th, eventually @Tornado77.  You may also wish to play with holding ctrl when you click to select a face, that'll select a path of faces from where you last clicked to where you just clicked.  This makes things SO much faster for most complex selections.  If not, C for Circle-Select is probably useful instead.

Comment: I think especially for this case the procedural solution makes no sense what so ever. I mean it is procedural and stuff but such textures should either be painted to have even more freedom or assigned like you showed if you dont care about realism (the edge between white and black is very hard and you can not have any kind of transition)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simpler (fewer edges and vertices) with a subsuf modifier so you can get a smooth cylinder on the render with a simple UV unwrap.
also, you could use different materials (black and white) on certain faces of the cilinder to have the same and more manageable results